# How to make the chacter detect stairs and react to it

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I don't know much of python, and I would like to make my character detect the stairs and look down (2 degrees in x axis) when upon it. I've tried using a Near sensor in the stairs (like a beacon) sending the Message "stairs" and make my character detect the message, activating the Motion Actuator to rotate in X. The problem is when the Message is detected by the character, he starts an endless rotation - a loop. I guess he is rotating 2 degrees again and again. How can I make him look down while upon the stairs and get back to the default rotation (0 degrees) afterwards? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to change the action mode to play, and you might have it set to "loop stop" or "loop end".

[image]

Here is a list of the play-modes for your benefit.

- **PLAY**- plays the action once on a positive pulse.
- **PING-PONG**- plays the animation forward and backward
- **FLIPPER**- plays the animation first forward, then after a negative pulse plays it backward.
- **LOOP-STOP**- will play the animation over and over as long as it has a positive pulse.
- **LOOP-END**- Like loop stop, but even after positive pulse is gone, it will finish playing the animation cycle it is in.
- **PROPERTY**- plays the animation based on a value from an existing game property.